# How or where can I set a JavaScript handler which gets executed when a specific region is executed or rerendered?

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces

For example you have a `rich:panel` (arbitrary choice, or any other component) like this:

```
<rich:panel>
    <p>
        Test Text Test Text Test Text.
    </p> 
</rich:panel>
```

How would you add a JavaScript handler which does something (anything) once this `rich:panel` (possibly containing several inputs or whatever) gets executed and/or rerendered (by whoever)?

Actually I want the handler called **before** it gets executed or rerendered, that is before the actual RichFaces.ajax() call happens, assuming that is how it is triggered in the browser.

Comment: Tell JSF impl/version and RF version and how exactly you're firing ajax requests.